# Как правильно должна выглядеть запись?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Почему-то при следующей записи в Firefox кастомный курсор начинает лагать:

```js
$("html").mousemove(function(e) {
  customCursor.style.transform = customCursor.style.WebkitTransform = customCursor.style.MsTransform = ('translateY(' + e.clientY + 'px) translateX(' + e.clientX + 'px)');
});
```

```css
.cursorWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: .1s;
}

div.customCursor {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .1s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursorWrapper" id="customCursor">
  <div class="customCursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Следующая запись не работает:" - где Вы видели css-свойство `"transform: translate3d("`?

Comment: Что значит - *кастомный курсор начинает лагать*?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Перемещается по экрану рывками, как будто цепляется о что-то.

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера никто не сможет вам помочь. Добавьте пример кода, на котором бы воспроизводилась описанная вами проблема.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Всё дело в свойстве Transition у .customCursor, убираем его и все идет плавно, но как реализовать тоже самое, но с задержкой анимации чтобы при этом она была плавной, а не рывками.
В кач-ве примера сайт: http://ibudakov.ru/
Там та же проблема с курсором и с фотографией при движении мышки в Firefox

Comment: в Chrome такой проблемы не наблюдается

Comment: Надо добавить воспроизводимый пример прямо в вопрос! Вот видите, у вас там свойство transition  есть, а мы и не знаем об этом. Добавляйте воспроизводимый пример прямо в вопрос!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Сейчас упакую сниппет.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko В таком виде сейчас реализация, при просмотре кода в хроме или просто в Firefox дико лагает кастомный курсор, в общем, увидите сами

Comment: Может подскажите как поступить..

Comment: У меня лаг воспроизводится только в Edge. В остальных браузерах норм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть предположение, что лаги из-за того, что событие mousemove происходит слишком часто. Что бы этого избежать, можно попробовать использовать `throttle`.

В примере, для быстроты, я подключил `underscore`. Функцию `throttle` сможете написать сами.
Также, лучше использовать `top` и `left` для позиционирования элемента, они менее затратные по ресурсам (в *Edge* так уж точно).

```js
$("html").mousemove(_.throttle(function(e) {
  customCursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
  customCursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
}, 50));
```

```css
.cursorWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: .1s;
}

div.customCursor {
  position: absolute;
  transition: .1s;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cursorWrapper" id="customCursor">
  <div class="customCursor"></div>
</div>
```